# Two equations on separate lines in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating an rmarkdown document and need to have two equations under each sub-heading, each equation on a separate line. I have tried double backslash but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Code below

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

# When Program = 0

\begingroup\Large
\begin{equation*}
\beta_{0i} = 48.78 + 5.78(0) = 48.78\\  
\beta_{1i} = 2 + 5.27(0) = 2
\end{equation*}
\endgroup

# When Program = 1

\begingroup\Large
\begin{equation*}
\beta_{0i} = 48.78 + 5.78(1) = 54.56\\ 
\beta_{1i} = 2 + 5.27(1) = 7.27 
\end{equation*}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace `equation*` by `align*`. This also provides an option to align the two equations using `&`:

```
---
title: "Aligned equations"
output: pdf_document
---

\begin{align*}
\beta_{0i} &= 48.78 + 5.78(0) = 48.78\\  
\beta_{1i} &= 2 + 5.27(0) = 2
\end{align*}
```

[image: Output]

See [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A) for additional explanations.

---

Note that the sample document in the question misses an `\endgroup`.

Comment: Thankyou @CL. That is very helpful. But this gets rid of my large font. How do I restore this?

Comment: You can still increase the font size as explained in your other question. I just removed the font size commands because they're not relevant here.

Comment: Yes I found that out by experimentation. This is the second time this week you've helped me with LaTex/markdown stuff. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Just a well-meant advice: Make sure you really understand the code presented in answers to your questions (like: which code is responsible for the font size; which forthe equation itself ...). Otherwise, they won't help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# When Program = 0

$$
\begingroup\Large
\begin{aligned}
\beta_{0i} = 48.78 + 5.78(0) = 48.78\\  
\beta_{1i} = 2 + 5.27(0) = 2
\end{aligned}
\endgroup
$$

# When Program = 1

$$
\begingroup\Large
\begin{aligned}
\beta_{0i} = 48.78 + 5.78(1) = 54.56\\ 
\beta_{1i} = 2 + 5.27(1) = 7.27 
\end{aligned}
\endgroup
$$
```

Output:
[image]